# How to Get children of child nodes from Firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: my database]:

```
class UserAccountSettings {
    private String user_id;
    private String name ;
    private float rate;
    private String profile_photo;
    private ArrayList<Activity> activities ;
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the actual data that you want to get?

Comment: i want get UserAccountSettings's  activities !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display those values, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference activitiesRef = rootRef.child("user_account_settings").child(uid).child("activities");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String user_id = dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue(String.class);
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        float rate = dataSnapshot.child("rate").getValue(Float.class);
        String profile_photo = dataSnapshot.child("profile_photo").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", user_id + " / " +
            profile_photo + " / " +
            rate + " / " +
            profile_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
activitiesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
mVeg... / Debbebi / 0 / http://...
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Your code is perfect but 1 question is there.
How to get "location" data in your code?

Comment: @ravi152 Thanks! I don't understand about what location you are you talking but I recommend you post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: @Alex Mamo location filed which is in question firebase table.
i talk about that location which is in every table below description text.

Answer (score 0):

1. declare a Data baseReference object (edit the string "azone" to match with your node key):

   ```
   DatabaseReference userSettingRef = 
                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                           .child("azone")
                           .child("user_account_settings")
                           .child(getUserId());
   ```
2. add a ValueEventListener:

   ```
   userSettingRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                       UserAccountSettings setting = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings .class);
                   if (setting!= null) {
                      // do something here

                   }

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   // Getting Post failed, log a recipientMessage
                   Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                   // ...
               }
           });
   ```